# Would the other Picard Maneuver work in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, clothing

The [joking comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/would-the-picard-maneuver-work-in-the-star-wars-universe#comment19736_10890) in response to [this original question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/would-the-picard-maneuver-work-in-the-star-wars-universe)

> [Would the Picard Maneuver work in the Star Wars universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/would-the-picard-maneuver-work-in-the-star-wars-universe)

is:

> Sure, tugging on either side of your uniform shirt to straighten it should work for any universe. :)

But would it?

## Have we actually seen something approximating a long-sleeved T-shirt in *Star Wars*?

(Of course the reason this question even makes sense is that for the most part, it appears that *Star Wars* characters appear in robes, tunics or armor)

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens:   That belongs on the **other** question

Comment: Downvoter:   Have you no sense of humour?

Comment: Shouldn't any of the Imperial Officers uniforms count? or are you calling those jackets and not t-shirts so they do not fit your criteria?

Comment: @Skooba, most of them look like they are attached to the pants or extend way past the belt,  so no need to be pulled down.

Comment: re: [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33351592#33351592) - Nice!

Comment: Ha! Brilliant! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the base layer of a Storm Trooper's uniform count?

[image: FN-2187]

[image]

Comment: assuming this is the same undergarment from his armor, probably not. Stormtrooper armor undergarments are a "new skin, a tough black body glove that seal[s] itself as [the wearer] climbs in" - source: Twilight Company: Battlefront (new canon book). We can likely presume that this same garment is similar or better now w/ the First Order

Comment: Whatever this is, it appears the Picard maneuver could be performed on it, so that gets an upvote.    (and adding another picture)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Han Solo rocks a long-sleeve tee in A New Hope

Comment: Playing devil's advocate here, that is tucked in, so for all we know it's a bodysuit.

Comment: It can't be a bodysuit, they wear them in the *future*.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - This is a space western. It's far more likely to be [long johns](https://youtu.be/SrJEWL6QHzo?t=1m35s).

Comment: @Valorum-  space opera - so it's more likely to be the chambermaid's undergarment

Answer (score 1):

Luke in the Return of the Jedi-his shirt was long-sleeved and all black. From the moment he removes his robe in the rancor pit, all the way to the ending.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer please? Sounds more like a comment at this point.

Comment: I agree. See http://scottandtemphotography.com/graflexSaber/219421_442066315844975_522145585_o.jpg

Comment: @king, see [this comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143955/would-the-other-picard-maneuver-work-in-the-star-wars-universe#comment366553_143956)